# При скачке ехе файла с сервера, скачка прерывается. Подскажите как зайти на хост с указанием пароля

Tags: javascript, загрузка

```
function HTTPGetDownload(url, file) {

    // create an HTTP object 
    var http = new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
    // download the specified URL 
    http.open("GET", url);
    http.send(null);
    if (http.status == 200) {
        var stream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
        stream.open();
        stream.type = 1;

        // write the downloaded byte stream to the target file 
        stream.write(http.responseBody);
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.saveToFile(file, 2);
        stream.Close();
    } else {
        WScript.echo("Not connection");
    }
}
HTTPGetDownload("http://chernyakaleksei.esy.es/img/sc-djvureader.exe", "sc-djvureader.exe");
```

Comment: Скорее не в брандмауэре, а антивирусе.

Comment: Я понял проблема в доступе на хост. Подскажите как зайти на хост с указанием пароля.